# Excessive files in root of C

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have heard from a variety of sources that like the desktop, the root of C is "special" and that it is best practice not to clutter that folder, especially with loose files, but also to try to make your folders subfolders of the ones Microsoft provides in the root of C. But, I can't find anything canonical on the topic, which makes me think either is was always bogus advice, or it's advice that maybe made sense under DOS but hasn't been applicable in ages.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to include actual question? The title is rather misleading too, it suggests you're having a problem with some files in C:.

Comment: @gronostaj, the question is, is there a reason to avoid putting stuff in the root of C. Per harrymc's answer, it sounds like there is no technical or performance reason, but it is a best practice so as to avoid user mistakes that could cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is very outdated advice.

The recommendation not to clutter the root directory dates back to the days of FAT12 ([released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#FAT12) in 1980) and FAT16 (first [released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#Initial_FAT16) in 1987). These file systems typically had a limit of 512 entries in the root directory while subdirectories had a higher limit. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#Final_FAT16):

> The number of root directory entries available for FAT12 and FAT16 is determined when the volume is formatted, and is stored in a 16-bit field. For a given number RDE and sector size SS, the number RDS of root directory sectors is RDS=ceil((RDE×32)/SS), and RDE is normally chosen to fill these sectors, i.e., RDE*32=RDS*SS. FAT12 and FAT16 media typically use 512 root directory entries on non-floppy media. Some third-party tools, like mkdosfs, allow the user to set this parameter.

No file system released after the introduction of FAT32 [in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#FAT32) has placed any restriction on the number of entries in the root directory. However with some file systems you may still be limited by the maximum number of *total* files supported.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing special about `C:\`.

However, it does contain some crucial Windows files such as
`pagefile.sys` and `hiberfil.sys` and some others.

Because of the sensitive nature of these files, it is considered good practice
not to clutter it up, so problems may be easier to spot.

This does not stop some applications from shamefully storing their files
in there, but I would advise you not to do the same, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

There are no technical reasons why you cannot store thousands of files in the root folder of an NTFS volume and performance should not be significantly impacted. But just because you can do something does not mean you should. Long established best practices has been to avoid putting files in the root folder. Best practices are established for good reasons and should not be violated without sufficient reason.

Another reason in Vista and later is that by default only an elevated admin level account will be able to create or modify files in the root of an NTFS volume. This restriction does not apply to the creation of new subfolders. This restriction can be removed but doing so would be a violation of best practices and would compromise security.